# PHP & CSS - Hide element if other field is filled in

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm editing a Dealer locator in Wordpress, and I need the modify a few fields. 
I need to hide a field if the other field is filled in.

**The scenario:**

If the user fills in the Address field and leaves the Address2 field blank, The element Address shows. 
I solved that part, but now i'm struggling with the next part. If the user fills in the Address2 field, it needs to show address2 and hide the Address

The code i'm using right now:

```
function custom_listing_template() {

global $wpsl, $wpsl_settings;

$listing_template = '<li class="my_change_list" data-store-id="<%= id %>">' . "\r\n";

$listing_template .= "\t\t" . '<div class="locator_wrap_left">' . "\r\n";
$listing_template .= "\t\t" . '<div class="locator_title">' . "\r\n";
$listing_template .= "\t\t\t\t" . wpsl_store_header_template( 'listing' ) . "\r\n";
$listing_template .= "\t\t" . '</div>' . "\r\n";
$listing_template .= "\t\t" . '<div class="locator_left">' . "\r\n";
$listing_template .= "\t\t\t" . '<p><%= thumb %>' . "\r\n";

$listing_template .= "\t\t\t\t" . '<span class="wpsl-street street1"><%= address %></span>' . "\r\n";
$listing_template .= "\t\t\t\t" . '<% if (address2) {  %>' . "\r\n";
$listing_template .= "\t\t\t\t" . ' <span class="wpsl-street street2"><%= address2 %></span>' . "\r\n";
$listing_template .= "\t\t\t\t" . '<% } %>' . "\r\n";
$listing_template .= "\t\t\t\t" . '<span>' . wpsl_address_format_placeholders() . '</span>' . "\r\n";
$listing_template .= "\t\t\t\t" . '<span class="wpsl-country"><%= country %></span>' . "\r\n";
$listing_template .= "\t\t\t" . '</p>' . "\r\n";
$listing_template .= "\t\t" . '</div>' . "\r\n";
```

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to help!

```
document.getElementById('street1').style.display = 'none';
```

**EDIT**: I'm trying to Avoid javascript right now since it's a PHP file.

Comment: `street1` is a class, not an ID.

Comment: downvoted for op posting a javascript question and then insisting on a php solution, which is not even possible. also the question is not tagged php.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
var eles = document.getElementsByClassName('street1');
for(var i=eles.length; ele--;) ele[i].style.display = 'none';
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('street1').style.display = 'none';
```

as `street1` is a class not an ID and `getElementsByClassName` returns multiple elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didn't make clear that I'm avoiding Javascript since this is a php file, and the basic structure is PHP Your answer would work if I was using Javascript. Thank you for your time!

Comment: first of all, your code sample is javascript and php is not even tagged in the question. second, php renders text and sends it to the browser. php has literally no ability to hide things in the dom once they are sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

`street1` is a  `class` element, not an `id`.

You need to use `document.getElementsByClassName('street1').style.display = 'none';` instead of `document.getElementById('street1').style.display = 'none';`

Also you have to iterate all over the elements to be able to hide them:

```js
var street1 = document.getElementsByClassName('street1');

for (var x = 0; x < street1.length; x++) {
  street1[x].style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<span class='street1'>elem 1</span>
<span class='street1'>elem 2</span>
<span class='street1'>elem 3</span>
<span class='street1'>elem 4</span>
```

And a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oon984ah/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exmple of two controls, type in one and the ohter shows up.

[JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/z0cfr2xg/)

What you do is use the `placeholder-shown`selector. You can make the placeholder a white space if you do not want it to show.

This is the code:

Html:

```
  <input type="text" id="aa" placeholder=" ">
    <input type="text" id="bb">
```

CSS:

```
#aa:placeholder-shown ~ #bb{
display:none;
}
```